# How to get a dictionary key by value from a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key, key-value

I have a dictionary

```
game_objects = {
    ('wall', 0): {'position': (0, 0), 'passable': False, 'interactable': False, 'char': '#'},
    ('wall', 1): {'position': (0, 1), 'passable': False, 'interactable': False, 'char': '#'},
    ('player',): {'position': (1, 1), 'passable': True, 'interactable': True, 'char': '@', 'coins': 0},
    ('soft_wall', 11): {'position': (1, 4), 'passable': False, 'interactable': True, 'char': '%'}
}
```

i need to make a function which will  get a dictionary key by value from a nested dictionary. For example:

```
get_objects_by_coords((0, 1)) == [('wall', 1)]
get_objects_by_coords((1, 1)) == [('player',)]
get_objects_by_coords((2, 1)) == []
```

Here is what i did:

```
def get_objects_by_coords(position):
    for position in game_objects.values():
        if position in game_objects.values():
            return game_objects.keys()


print(get_objects_by_coords((0, 0)))
```

but the answer is not correct

```
dict_keys([('wall', 0), ('wall', 1), ('player',), ('soft_wall', 11)])
```

and I need only this part

```
[('wall', 1)]
```

so, how can I improve my code? I know this code is awful, but I'm just learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```py
def get_objects_by_coords(position):
    return [key for key, val in game_objects.items()
                for k, v in val.items() if k == 'position' and v == position]

assert get_objects_by_coords((0, 1)) == [('wall', 1)]
assert get_objects_by_coords((1, 1)) == [('player',)]
assert get_objects_by_coords((2, 1)) == []
```

Comment: almost, but i don't need "import" operation. I wish I could write the rules, but I can't :) so i need to write a code without import

Comment: @Ruslan - those imports are just type hints. You can ignore them and delete all their appearances - this will not matter to the code, at least not for your purpose. I edited the answer for your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning every `dict` key, and not the key you found. I would recommend you to take a look into [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) method, which return a pair of key, value. Therefore, your function could look like:

```py
def get_objects_by_coords(game_objects, position):
    for key, value in game_objects.items():
        if position == value.get('position', (None,)):
            return key
get_objects_by_coords(game_objects, (0, 1)) # == ('wall', 1)
```

Also, if you are going to iterate many times over the dictionary in your program, I wouldn't use the Data Structure as you did, because although looking into a `dict` key i O(1), iterating over it to get to a value is O(n). Furthermore, I wouldn't use a global variable (you function uses `game_objects` variable even though it doesn't receives it as an argument), as it's not a good practice.

Hope this helped! Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: It is a good advice, i will read about items method, but the code fails on the site where I got this assignment from. Your code is right, but the program on the site says that this is not answer. But i think i can fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your entire structure is wrong.  What about this?

```
game_objects =  [
    [
        {
            'type':'wall',
            'item_no':0,
            'passsable':False,
            'interacable':False,
            'char':'#'
        },
        
        {
            'type':'wall',
            'item_no':1,
            'passsable':False,
            'interacable':False,
            'char':'#'
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            'type':'player',
            'item_no':None,
            'passable':True,
            'interactable': True,
            'char': '@',
            'coins': 0
        },
        {
            'type':None
        },
        {
            'type':None
        },
        {
            'type':None
        },
        {
            'type':'soft_wall',
            'item_no': 11,
            'passable': False,
            'interactable': True,
            'char': '%'}
    ],
    
]
```

Output

```
game_objects[1][4]

{'type': 'soft_wall',
 'item_no': 11,
 'passable': False,
 'interactable': True,
 'char': '%'}

game_objects[0][1]

{'type': 'wall',
 'item_no': 1,
 'passsable': False,
 'interacable': False,
 'char': '#'}
```

Comment: Can't change the structure of the dictionary, it was default